# image fetching throug form from google not working?

Tags: php, html, image

I have tried making a from and wrote a script that fetch image from google but it does not display any image nor it gives any error what shall i do.
here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Images</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="Post">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Text:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="image" id="ImageType" value=""></td>
<td><input type="Submit" value="Click to Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br>

</body>
</html> 

<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$search_query = $_POST['image'];


 // $search_query = "love";
 $search_query = urlencode( $search_query );
 $html = file_get_html( "https://www.google.com/search?q=$search_query& tbm=isch" );
 // $image_container = $html->find('div#rcnt', 0);
  $images = $html->find('img');
  $image_count = 10; //Enter the amount of images to be shown
  $i = 0;
  foreach($images as $image){
    if($i == $image_count) break;
    $i++;
    // DO with the image whatever you want here (the image element is '$image'):
    echo $image;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I am not getting any error as I said above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_html( "https://www.google.com/search?q=$search_query& tbm=isch" );
```

should be

```
$html = file_get_html( "https://www.google.com/search?q=$search_query&tbm=isch" );
```

A space between `search_query&` and `tbm` needs to be removed.

**EDIT**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include "simple_html_dom.php";
    $search_query = $_POST['image'];
    $html = file_get_html("https://www.google.com/search?q=$search_query&tbm=isch");
    $images = $html->find('img');
    $image_count = 10; //Enter the amount of images to be shown
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        if ($i == $image_count)
            break;
        $i++;
        // DO with the image whatever you want here (the image element is '$image'):
        echo $image;
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT - 2**
You should give name attribute to submit button such as:

`<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Click to Submit">`

OR use :
`if (isset($_POST['image'])) {` instead of `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

Comment: buddy thats not the problem itried removing the space...

Comment: Thats a working code. I can fetch the image with this code. The issue was with the extra space only.

Comment: this work for me to but i want it to be work as user type in the form.

Comment: form is also working @ashish

Comment: name attribute is missing in submit button as seen in EDIT-2. You are not getting any error because it never goes inside the if condition.

Comment: you save my day..thanks...one more problem....if I change image_count from 10 to 100 I am getting only 20 images why it is so..please reply..